# restart audio file when it's nearly finish

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio

I am playing an audio file using html5 and Jquery. The file's length is 5 seconds. I am trying to restart the file when the current time is 3sec. But the problem is it always ends to 5sec.

I was trying to create a jsfiddle but I can't host the audio file so I am placing all my code here.

On page load there will be a jquery function called playAudio().

HTML Code:

```
<audio id="audio_generic"> //I can write loop but I don't want as the end of audio file is bit cracky.
  <source src="engine_loop.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"  />  
  <source src="engine_loop.ogg" type="audio/ogg">                    
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</audio >
```

Jquery :

```
function playaudio()
{
var checkaudio = false;
$('#audio_generic').trigger('play');
$audioplayer = $('#audio_generic').get(0);
$audioplayer.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(event)
{
   if ($audioplayer.currentTime > 3)
   {    
    //$audioplayer.play(); 
playaudio();                 
   }
});
}
```

Please let me know if you have any better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it work but try to add the EventListener on document ready once because now you add it every time you go inside playaudio function.

Comment: Thanks mate but for some reason I need to put it under a function not on document ready.